# How do I fix cannot borrow `` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust

Description: I am running this code but I keep getting the following error.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*graph` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
   --> chain/chain.rs:111:12
    |
103 |         for tx in graph.iter() {
    |                   ------------ immutable borrow occurs here
...
111 |         if is_valid_transaction(graph, selected[i].1) == true {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------^^^^^^
    |            |                           |
    |            |                           immutable borrow later used here
    |            mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<&(&str, Transaction)>`
   --> chain/chain.rs:111:40
    |
111 |         if is_valid_transaction(graph, selected[i].1) == true {
    |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Transaction`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

What makes this unique (I hope) and not a duplicate is when I change `graph.iter` to `graph.iter_mut()` I get this error.

```
 error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*graph` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> chain/chain.rs:103:19
    |
103 |         for tx in graph.iter_mut() {
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `*graph` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*graph` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> chain/chain.rs:111:33
    |
103 |         for tx in graph.iter_mut() {
    |                   ---------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
111 |         if is_valid_transaction(graph, selected[i].1) == true {
    |                                 ^^^^^  -------- first borrow later used here
    |                                 |
    |                                 second mutable borrow occurs here
```

Also, it seems like I need lifetime parameters, or else I will get more errors in my code.

Code (import the rand crate here: https://crates.io/crates/rand):

```
pub struct Transaction {
    pub sender_address: &'static str,
    pub receiver_address: &'static str,
    pub amount: f64,
    pub timestamp: String,
    pub signature: &'static str,
    pub weight: u128,
    pub edges: Vec<Transaction>, // I have no clue the true type
    pub index: usize,
}


fn is_valid_transaction (graph: &mut Vec<(&'static str, Transaction)> , transaction: Transaction) -> bool {
    if transaction.amount == 0.0 {
        println!("You can't send 0");
        return false;}
        

    if transaction.amount < 0.0 {
        println!("You can't send negative quantities");
        return false;}

    if transaction.sender_address == transaction.receiver_address {
        println!("You can't send to yourself");
        return false;}

    if transaction.signature.len() != 64 {
        println!("Invalid signature");
        return false;}

    else {return true;}
}

fn generate_random_indexes (graph: &mut Vec<(&'static str, Transaction)>) -> (usize, usize) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let index_one = rng.gen_range(0..5000);
    let mut index_two = rng.gen_range(0..5000);
    while index_one == index_two {
        index_two = rng.gen_range(0..5000);
    }
    return (index_one, index_two);
}

// (&'a mut (&'static str, Transaction), &'a mut (&'static str, Transaction), u128)

fn select_edges_and_confirm_transactions <'a> (graph: &'a mut Vec<(&'static str, Transaction)>)
    -> ((&'a str, Transaction), (&'a str, Transaction), u128) {
    let (index_one, index_two) = generate_random_indexes(graph);
    let mut selected: Vec<(&(&'static str, Transaction))> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..2 {
        for tx in graph.iter() {
            if tx.1.index == index_one || tx.1.index == index_two {
                selected.push(tx);
            }
        }
    }

    for i in 0..2 {
        if is_valid_transaction(graph, selected[i].1) == true {
            continue;
        } else {
            panic!("Found an invalid transaction!");
        }
    }

    let tx_one = selected[0].clone();
    let tx_two = selected[1].clone();
    let cumulative = &selected[0].1.weight + &selected[1].1.weight;

    return (tx_one, tx_two, cumulative);
}
```

Comment: You're not showing the `is_valid_transaction` function, but I suspect from the error message that it takes a `&mut Vec<…>` as its first parameter. Does it really need a mutable borrow of the graph?

Comment: It is used in a function that needs it to be mutable, hence that is why it is mutable.

Comment: Would you like to see the whole file?

Comment: We need at least the prototype for `is_valid_transaction` (the one you've added is obviously wrong since it doesn't take any parameters) and ideally a [mre] (best would be if you can reproduce the issue on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable graph is not used in `fn is_valid_transation(...)`. Get rid of it.

If you don't want to because you'll add it later you can clone the `tx` and change the `selected` vector to not contain references to tuples but tuples directly. To do that you need to derive the Clone trait on the struct `Transaction`. By pushing `tx` (which is of type `&(&str, Transaction)`) to a vector you're merely pushing a reference to an item already present in your `graph` vector, which compiler complains about because you're also borrowing the vector mutably in the function call. This function call could change `graph`, changing the item you withdraw from `selected`. It's better to clone the data than try to borrow it mutably and immutably at the same time, or borrow it mutably twice.

Also change the is_valid_transaction signature to take a &Transaction instead of Transaction, and pass selected[i].1 as a reference. You probably can do that with the rest of the functions in your code in general.
[Here's a link to the playground with all that done](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=69899bc3ced1359c319eebceab757daa)

Comment: Thanks! Also, thanks for letting me know the redundancy as well